# How to Delete/Remove a Property from a SharedObject in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a SharedObject in which I'm saving some data in a flash app. I'm trying to remove some saved data but it doesn't work.

```
trace(delete(localData.data[key]));
```

The delete command returns true, but when I reload the data it looks it was not deleted.

As of now the best solution was to "localData.clear();" all the data and then to save it without the fields I want to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the flush() method to "commit" your changes:

> Immediately writes a locally persistent shared object to a local file.
>   If you don't use this method, Flash Player writes the shared object to
>   a file when the shared object session ends — that is, when the SWF
>   file is closed, when the shared object is garbage-collected because it
>   no longer has any references to it, or when you call
>   SharedObject.clear() or SharedObject.close().

More info here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#flush()